# POST request with value FALSE turns to TRUE in db

Tags: php, symfony

Good mornings all,  I make a POST request with the Type field (tinyint) in my unit tests. I give it the value FALSE. When I check in the database, the Type field is 1 so TRUE. I don't know how this is possible and it happens to me several times on my unit tests.

The POST request with the column type :

```
 "title" => "Une fausse formation"
  "number" => "faux-numer0"
  "organism" => "Un faux organisme"
  "type" => false
  "status" => 0
  "costs" => array:2 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "title" => "Frais pédagogiques"
      "type" => 0
      "amount" => 102.5
      "isCollective" => true
    ]
    1 => array:4 [
      "title" => "Frais de transport"
      "type" => 0
      "amount" => 10
      "isCollective" => true
    ]
  ]
  "sessions" => []
  "visibility" => 2
]
```

the row that was inserted into the table :

```
 "title" => "Une fausse formation"
  "number" => "faux-numer0"
  "type" => true
  "status" => 0
  "organism" => "Un faux organisme"
  "visibility" => array:2 [
    "establishment" => []
    "employees" => array:1 [
      0 => []
    ]
  ]
  "costs" => array:2 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "title" => "Frais pédagogiques"
      "type" => 0
      "amount" => "102.50"
      "is_collective" => true
    ]
    1 => array:4 [
      "title" => "Frais de transport"
      "type" => 0
      "amount" => "10.00"
      "is_collective" => true
    ]
  ]
]
```

Here is my field declaration in the Entity:

```
/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`type`", type="boolean")
 * @Serializer\Groups({"get_employee", "get_training", "get_trainings", "get_training_user", "get_training_session"})
 */
private $type;
```

This is my POST TEST request :

```
 public function testPostTraining($user, $data, $result)
    {
               
        $this->authUser($user[0], $user[1], $user[2]);

        // Retrieve created visibility id
        $visibilityData = array(
            'establishment' => 1
        );
        $this->apiCall('POST', '/api/secure/trainings/visibilities.json', $visibilityData);
        // Check status code (visibility created)
        $this->assertEquals(201, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        $data['visibility'] = json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent(), true)['id'];
        $this->apiCall('POST', '/api/secure/trainings.json', $data);

       // Check status code (created)
        $this->assertEquals(201, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        // Check if id is returned
        $response = json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent(), true);
        
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('id', $response);
        //$this->assertInternalType('integer', $response['id']);
        $this->assertEquals('integer', gettype($response['id']));
        
        // Check data
        $this->apiCall('GET', '/api/secure/trainings/'.$response['id'].'.json');
        $training = json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent(), true);
        // Remove ids
        $this->recursive_unset($training, 'id');
        $this->recursive_unset($training, 'created_at');
        $this->recursive_unset($training, 'updated_at');
        $this->recursive_unset($training['visibility']['establishment'], 'roles');

        // Check content
        $this->assertEquals($training, $result);
    }
```

The data of the post request :

```
$data_two= array(
    'title'             =>  'Une vrai formation',
    'number'            =>  'vrai-numer0',
    'organism'          =>  'Un vrai organisme',
    'type'              =>  false,
    'status'            =>  1,
    'costs'             =>  array(
        array(
            'title'     =>  'Frais pédagogiques',
            'type'      =>  1,
            'amount'    =>  10.25,
            'isCollective' => true
        ),
    ),
    'sessions'          =>  array()
);
```

This is the POST controller :

```
   public function postAction(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            if (($employee = $this->getEmployee()) == null)
                return FOSView::create(null, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);

            $manager = $this->getTrainingManager();
            $training = $manager->createTraining();
            $form = $this->createForm(TrainingType::class, $training, array(
                'method' => $request->getMethod()
            ));
            $this->removeExtraFields($request, $form);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('create', $training);
                $manager->save($training);

                $dispatcher = $this->eventDisptacher;
                $event = new TrainingActionEvent($training, $this->getEmployee(), $request->getMethod());
                $dispatcher->dispatch($event,TrainingActionEvent::TRAINING_ACTION);

                return $training;
            }
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            return FOSView::create($e->getMessage(), Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        return FOSView::create($form, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Comment: You should try avoid writting to a database in unit test. You should be isolating your code so you can just test the logic.

To help answer your question can you show us the code used to update the database and the code for your entity.

Comment: In your app if you look at your actual entity you will see the type annotation as *type="boolean"*. Doctrine ORM is converting this under the hood to 0 or 1 for your db. Now that you are doing it manually, you will have to convert it. That is why *false* is evaluating as 1 for the *tinyint* as it is "something" so it becomes true.

Comment: Hello @Bossman, I understood your answer. Indeed my field is in boolean type. However, when I create my POST request with the value 0 instead of FALSE, I still end up with the value TRUE in database.

Comment: @oracle972, obviously there must be something else, hard to tell without seeing your test logic.

Comment: @Bossman I posted the test and controller code. This is a POST request '/api/secure/trainings.json'. Then I retrieve this same line with a GET thanks to the id and finally I compare the two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The POST requests in my unit tests were incorrectly formatted.

Before :

```
private function apiCall($method, $endpoint, $parameters=array())
{

$this->client->request($method, $endpoint, $parameters);
return json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent(), true);

}
```

After :

```
private function apiPostCall($method, $endpoint, $parameters=array())
    {           
            $this->client->request(
                $method,
                $endpoint,
                [],
                [],
                ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'],
                json_encode($parameters)
            );    
    return json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent(),true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `CheckboxType` for the boolean field in your form definition.
If you take a look at the [class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/CheckboxType.php#L36), you can see that a [`BooleanToStringTransformer`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/BooleanToStringTransformer.php) is used to convert the submitted value to a real boolean.
Only the configured `value` (default: `'1'`) is converted to `true`, and the configured `false_values` (default: `[null]`) are converted to `false`.

Going through the documentation in the `FOSRestBundle`, this issue has been resolved already: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/pull/883

See: https://fosrestbundle.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/body_listener.html#decoders

> If you want to be able to use a checkbox within a form and have true and false values (without any issue) you have to use: `fos_rest.decoder.jsontoform`

Comment: Thanks  @Fracsi for your comprehensive response. Indeed, I am using checkBoxType in my form.

I added  `body_listener:
                      enabled: true
                     decoders:
                               json: fos_rest.decoder.jsontoform
        body_converter:
        enabled: true`  in the packages/fos_rest.yaml   and still have the same problem.

Comment: I also have the same issue with fields that are float in db and when I fetch them are seen as strings. So it would be a doctrine configuration problem I think.

Comment: Hello @Fracsi , Do you have a other idea for my problem please ?

Comment: Check what is in the request object, before passing the data to the form. If the keys are still in the data, than the JsonToForm decoder does not work in your case. Maybe an older version of the bundle?

Comment: I checked in the object before passing the data to the form request and the field in question is empty although I specified false during the call. I'am using rest bundle 3.4 @Fracsi

Comment: when I dump the request object before passing the form,  my field is empty while I pass a value to it.

Comment: Field should be empty if false was given (that is the purpose of jsontoform converter).

Comment: I finally have new information. When I pass my unit tests, the value false is not inserted in the database. When I go through postman everything works fine. The problem would come from my unit tests. Yes the field is empty with postman too